# Jackson dataformat csv NoSuchMethodError createContentReference

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-dataformat-csv

I'm using `jackson-dataformat-csv 2.15.0` with following code to export my data into an text file

```
            List<HashMap<String, String>> data = <list of data>;
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new File(FILE_PATH));
            CsvSchema schema = null;
            CsvSchema.Builder schemaBuilder = CsvSchema.builder();
            // output verify list record
            if (data != null && !data.isEmpty()) {
                schema = schemaBuilder.addColumn("ID").addColumn("Date").build()
                        .withLineSeparator("\r").withHeader();

                CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
                mapper.writer(schema).writeValues(out).writeAll(data);
            }
            out.close();
```

But it just pop up error

```
2023-05-14 14:11:25,865 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-394) Exception in thread "Thread-394" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvFactory._createContentReference(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/io/ContentReference;

2023-05-14 14:11:25,865 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-394)     at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvFactory.createGenerator(CsvFactory.java:372)

2023-05-14 14:11:25,865 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-394)     at com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvFactory.createGenerator(CsvFactory.java:16)

2023-05-14 14:11:25,865 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-394)     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.createGenerator(ObjectWriter.java:703)

2023-05-14 14:11:25,865 ERROR [stderr] (Thread-394)     at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValues(ObjectWriter.java:789)
```

I have checked maven hierarchy, those conflicted jackson libs are ommited. I also checked the exported WAR that its `jackson-core`, `jackson-annotations`, `jackson-databind`, and `jackson-dataformat-csv` are `2.15.0` and no other old-duplicated lib. No error reported from my eclipse about method not found or otherwise. Does anyone know what happen about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With further digging and some tips from the jackson lib's member, it turn out that isn't my WAR's fault but JBoss. Their default setting would use a module call `resteasy-jackson2-provider` and it will be using `jackson-core` and `jackson-databind` as part of its dependencies even if your server config doesn't includes them. It's indirect dependency.

There are two ways to resolve this issue, I prefer first one for less trouble.

1. Exclude them in your `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`

   As I mentioned that this is **indirect dependency**. So the lib that you have to exclude would be `resteasy-jackson2-provider`. Add them all to exclusions if you're not sure that the other JBoss would include them or not.

   ```
   <exclusions>
       <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core" />
       <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind" />
       <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
   </exclusions>
   ```
2. Update JBoss's modules

   Well, this WILL be super annoying if you have many of them.